# Garbage collection reference variable within a Vector

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I am implementing garbage collection within an AS3 app.  In one part, several display objects are created within a loop like so:

```
for(var i:uint = 0; i <= this._exampleVector.length - 1; i++) 
{
   this._customText = new CustomTextObject(this._exampleVector[i].playlistText),  this._customTextWidth);
   this.addChild(this._customText);

  etc etc

  this._customTextVector.push(this._customText); // used for ref in garbage collection
}
```

I then perform my garbage collection preparation by looping through the _customTextVector variable.

```
for(var i:uint = 0; i <= this._customTextVector.length - 1; i++) 
{
  this.removeChild(this._customTextVector[i]);
  this._customTextVector[i].gcAllObjects();
  **this._customTextVector[i] = null;**
}
```

When I try to make the _customText within the _customTextVector null, this does not work.  It only makes the index inside the Vector null.  Any ideas on how to do this or another method to garbage collect?

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to do following after looping through all the indices

```
  _customTextVector =null;
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply @kasavbere, but I am trying to make the _customText variable null rather than the Vector itself (although I understand this needs too be done eventually)

Answer (score 0):

In order to cause the AS3 Garbage Collector to GC your objects, you need to remove all references to them (including event listeners). On the next GC pass, the object's memory will be freed. There is no way to directly, instantly "null" an object like you want.

If you're having issues with memory, have a look at [this post](http://tomgabob.blogspot.com/2009/11/as3-memory-management.html).

Comment: Hi @Sam DeHaan, I understand you can't instantly null objects but I thought you need to null them as well as removing them from the display list and removing event listeners, to prepare them for garbage collection?

Comment: @ChristopherGrigg That's correct. If you have no other references in your project, and no event listeners, what you have is enough. If not, you need to null or change any other references in your project, and be sure to remove event listeners (even weak ones don't always work right).

Comment: So that brings me to the original question which is how can I make all the actual _customText objects null that are created within the loop, maybe I could have worded it better!

Comment: @ChristopherGrigg **how** are you seeing that it isn't null?

Comment: I am utilising FB4 and setting a breakpoint just after the vars are made null. In the variables window I can see the last _customText var is not null.

Comment: @ChristopherGrigg The flash garbage collector [is not instantaneous](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/garbage_collection.html)